# Can a systemd service depend on a remote systemd service?

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to write a systemd `service` that depends on a **remote** systemd service. Is there any "standard" way of accomplishing something as weird as this? Use case for this is some legacy software that needs a remote endpoint to be ready at startup.

I know I could use something like [wait-for-this](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) in a service's `ExecStartPre` that checks/waits until some specific remote TCP port is available (and possibly write a simple `.socket` unit on the remote). But this seems like a bit of an overkill. Is there a method in systemd itself for communicating with another, remote systemd?

Comment: Are you able to check the remote service from service you are trying to write the systemd service? (like a network service like database, ssh, sftp etc)

Comment: I cannot modify the program being started by the `service`, but I can indeed modify the service file itself. Meaning I can write/use a script to do whatever is needed in for example `ExecStartPre`. My initial idea was to define a custom `.target` which would wait until the remote is good and ready, but modifying the service ought to be enough.

Comment: That is why they created systemd, for doing important stuff like that without needing to write shell script, wait a minute... it can't do it?

Comment: I sense a little sarcasm in that last comment :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remote systemd service opens some port in the remote server you can check if that port is open from your local systemd service. Using bash you can write something like

```bsh
while ! echo > /dev/tcp/remoteserver/someport; do
  echo "waiting for remote service..."
  sleep 5s
done
```

Of course, you need to tell systemd to don't start this service until the network is up https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Running_services_after_the_network_is_up

Comment: Maybe you are thinking in using while? Or that will wait if combined to systemd?

Comment: You're right, a while loop and a sleep between cycles is closer to the solution than that if. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I thought of doing as well, assuming that systemd itself does not support anything better.

Comment: AFAIK systemd has no option for this kind of external dependencies ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So I figured.. seems I'm going to have to go with this type of dummy while-try-sleep -loop.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like `ExecStartPre=systemctl --host=service-user@remote-host start remote-service` could be used in ExecStartPre of the local service file.

Comment: The `--host` is a useful mechanism for `systemctl` -- but is there an equivalent syntax for the `.service` file itself -- to be put into the `After` clause of the service' `[Unit]` section?